# Create PDF in Swift with clickable link in PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, swift3

I want to generate PDF from data with clickable link inside. I have created PDF using SimplePDF (https://github.com/nRewik/SimplePDF) library but couldn't find the way to how make link clickable.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as text on your pdf

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Life Saver!")
attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://www.stackoverflow.com", range: NSRange(location: 19, length: 55))
textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: But I am not able to use TextView through my library SimplePDF, otherwise it would work.

Comment: as per documentation, you can use it as follows,

pdf.addAttributedText( NSAttributedString )

Comment: I have tried this already but this doesn't work. Cause there should be user interaction enable for string. There is no UILabel, UITextView used so not able take user interation

Comment: you may want to color your link as a link: `attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue, NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue], range:NSRange(location: 19, length: 55))`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, that I created the PDF from a IB-constructed view. I used `writePDF` and rendered the entire view with `view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)`, and the attributed texts within the labels or text views weren't clickable (although they appeared well). So I had to add it as an extra text:

```
mutableString.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 200))
```

This is the core of my solution:

```
    let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: pdfView.bounds)

    do {
        try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { context in
            context.beginPage()
            pdfView.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
            mutableString.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 200))
        })
    } catch {
        print("Could not create PDF file: \(error)")
    }
```

This seems to be working from iOS 15 however.